# How to do json format using nltk

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, entity-relationship

How to do json format using nltk. Example:

```
tagged_sent = [('Rami', 'PERSON'), ('Eid', 'PERSON'), ('is', 'O'), ('studying', 'O'), ('at', 'O'), ('Stony', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('Brook', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('University', 'ORGANIZATION'), ('in', 'O'), ('NY', 'LOCATION')]
```

I want output like `json` format:

```
data = {
        'Rami Eid':{'job': 'engineer', 'location':'NY'},
        'GuruRaj Bagali':{'job': 'professor', 'location':
 'NY'}
       }
```

Comment: Your example output has information that isn't in the sentence ("Rami Eid is studying at Stony Brook University in NY" doesn't tell me that he is an engineer), so I'm not clear on what the scope of your question is. Converting the list into a dictionary is just a Python question, but are you also asking for NLP techniques, and if so what?

Comment: Just build a dictionary with the data you want, and use the `json` module to write it out. The source of the data is irrelevant.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35193400/how-to-do-json-format